# How can I assign multiple lists to a property of my object?

Tags: java, php, arrays, json, hashmap

I have a product object that has a number of properties like this

```
public class Product {
     private int deal_id;
     private String deal_key;
     private String deal_title;
     private String url_title;
     private int deal_value;
.........//setters and getters
}
```

Every product has a number of sizes that can also be 0. I want to assign sizes to my product from values in the json data I receive(below).
I am extending this class and now I need to add another property of size which is an array of arrays. I need to set it from json on the api that like this.

```
"size" : [ { "product_size_id": "695", "deal_id": "179", "size_name": "None", "quantity": "1", "size_id": "1" }, 
           { "product_size_id": "695", "deal_id": "179", "size_name": "None", "quantity": "1", "size_id": "1" } ]
```

How can I set this on my product object in JAVA. I have tried looking up Hashmaps and Arraylist but havent found a way to do it correctly.

Comment: This statement: `"How can I set this on my product object in JAVA."` isn't clear. Please try to re-phrase and clarify. If you're trying to add a collection of Products to the Product class, don't. It doesn't belong there.

Comment: Basically I am trying to add the size to product class.

Comment: Again, clarify. Is size a collection of Product objects? Again if it is, the correct answer is that you should not be trying to add this to Product. Yours sounds like an XY Problem where you're looking for a specific solution to an incorrect question. Better to tell us more of the overall problem you're trying to solve, not how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: I have added a bit more information. Tell me if the question is now clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object for Size with all your properties

```
public class Size {
    private int product_size_id;
    private int deal_id;
    private String size_name;
    private int quantity;
    private int size_id;
....setters and getters
}
```

Then you can set size as object and add it to Product as a List

```
private ArrayList<Size> yoursizes;
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Very easy solution but I could not think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that may help to find a solution to your problem.

First you may want to parse the JSON input. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) may help you to get this done.

Second I think you need a data structure that allows to assign multiple lists to a value (or something similar). There are libraries for Java to help you do this. [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) or [Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) are two examples.

Comment: Thanks. I already know how to parse json, let me read about assigning multiple lists to a value.